# Filing German tax refund 2019 from abroad

Tags: germany, taxes

I worked in Germany for the entire 2019 and now I have moved to the UK. I need to file for the tax refund for the year 2019. Can someone answer the following questions for me:

1. I do not have a Steuernummer (tax number) but I do have a tax identification number. Do I still need to provide my employer's Steuernummer on my tax refund application or can I just provide my tax identification number and that should be it? I am applying through SteuerGo and it is mentioned there that a new tax number is required if I do not have one as of now.
2. Do I need to fax or send all my documents by post as I am now living in the UK?
3. What documents do I need to provide along with my tax application? Do I need to provide my Abmeldung and air ticket as proof of my leaving Germany? Do I also need to provide my residence documents within the UK?
4. Do I just need to apply everything online or should I send my documents by fax as well?

Comment: What did the SteuerGo help desk say when you asked them these questions? https://www.howtogermany.com/faq/faq.php

Comment: What they are saying is kind of mixing with other comments that I am getting from other people.. If I don't get any firm answer, then I will stick with what SteuerGo is saying..